# Откат транзакций в JavaEE

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, java-ee, servlet

Возник вопрос на счет отката транзакций, допустим в сервлете.
Допустим, есть следующая ситуация:

```
doPost(args){
    DaoFactory daoFactory = DaoFactory.getInstance();
    UserDao userDao = daoFactory.getUserDao();
    userDao.addNewUserToDB(user);
    
    CarDao carDao = daoFactory.getCarDao();
    carDao.addNewCarToDB(car);
}
```

Теперь сам вопрос. Допустим, мы отловим исключение при добавлении автомобиля. И нам нельзя допустить, чтобы добавился пользователь без добавления автомобиля. Как откатить весь метод?

Код не настоящий, если кто не понял, просто что-то типа псевдо-кода.

Comment: Вопрос о J2EE или о JavaEE?

Comment: Используйте одну транзакцию в этом случае и делайте ролбэк , если что-то пошло не так.(В таком случае ни юзер , ни автомобиль не запишутся в базу)

Comment: JavaEE, описка.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [BMT](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) в JPA для маркировки транзакции. Или же вынести код отдельный бин к которому применить [CMT](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). He нужно писать весь код в сервлете, поскольку он не может управлять транзакциями.

Answer (score 0):

В Spring есть два способа формирования транзакций, либо с помощью аннотаций, либо рукописно(возможно с помощью AOP реализовать). А в чистой Java можно сделать выше абстракцию(TransactionManager) для всех сервисов и там реализовать откат или выполнение транзакций.